# TypeError: Cannot read property '$$phase' of null - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and trying to develop a simple app. The app consist of 2 pages(sections) which are list and details.

If I visit both page separately (manually enter the URL in the address bar), both pages loads fine without any error. But if I navigate to details page from list page, the console displays this error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$$phase' of null
at Object.$$debounceViewValueCommit (angular.min.js:293)
at Object.$setViewValue (angular.min.js:293)
at Array.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:315)
at m.$digest (angular.min.js:145)
at m.$apply (angular.min.js:147)
at l (angular.min.js:101)
at XMLHttpRequest.N.onload (angular.min.js:106)
```

However, the page still load fine but the error bothers me. What exactly is happening?

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'heroControllers']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    "use strict";
    $routeProvider.
    when('/list', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/list.html',
        controller: 'ListController'
    }).
    when('/details/:itemId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/details.html',
        controller: 'DetailsController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/list'
    });
}]);

//controller
var heroControllers = angular.module('heroControllers', []);

heroControllers.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    "use strict";
    $http.get('js/data.json').then(function (response) {
        $scope.hero = response.data;
        $scope.order = "nickname";
    });
}]);

heroControllers.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    "use strict";
    $http.get('js/data.json').then(function (response) {
        $scope.hero = response.data;
        $scope.whichItem = $routeParams.itemId;
    });
}]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular Demo</title>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h1><a href="#!/list">Heroes</a></h1>
                </div>
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**list.html**

```
<section>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input ng-model="query" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for heroes" autofocus>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Sort by: </label>
            <select ng-model="order">
                <option value="nickname">Nickname</option>
                <option value="name">Name</option>
            </select>

            <input ng-model="direction" type="radio" name="direction" checked>
            <label>Ascending</label>
            <input ng-model="direction" type="radio" name="direction" value="reverse">
            <label>Descending</label>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in hero | filter: query | orderBy: order:direction">
                <a href="#!/details/{{hero.indexOf(item)}}">
                    <img ng-src="images/{{item.imagename}}.png" alt="Photo of {{item.nickname}}">
                    <div>
                        <h2>{{item.nickname | uppercase}}</h2>
                        <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</section>
```

**details.html**

```
    <section>
        <div ng-model="hero" class="jumbotron">
            <h2>{{hero[whichItem].nickname}}</h2>
            <div>
                <h3>{{hero[whichItem].name}}</h3>
                <img ng-src="images/{{hero[whichItem].imagename}}.png" alt="Photo of {{hero[whichItem].imagename}}">
                <div>{{hero[whichItem].lore}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#!/list">&laquo; Back to search</a>
    </section>
```

**data.json**

```
[
    {
        "nickname" : "Sniper",
        "imagename" : "sniper",
        "name" : "Kardel Sharpeye",
        "lore" : "Bla... Bla... Bla..."
    },
    {
        "nickname" : "Io",
        "imagename" : "io",
        "name" : "Wisp",
        "lore" : "Bla... Bla... Bla..."
    },
    {
        "nickname" : "Timbersaw",
        "imagename" : "timbersaw",
        "name" : "Rizzrack",
        "lore" : "Bla... Bla... Bla..."
    }
]
```

Comment: It seems that it is an issue with the AngularJS v1.6.0-rc.2. I've changed to AngularJS v1.5.9 and the problem disappear. Thanks @nikky for pointing it out. I also notice the fragment identifier now is # instead of #!

Answer (score 1):

Use stable version of angularjs(latest for now is 1.5.9) to get rid of

> "TypeError: Cannot read property '$$phase' of null - AngularJS" 
>   error.

Comment: this actually breaks my app and caused an error `Error: $controller:ctrlreg
A controller with this name is not registered.`

Comment: I have modified your script file.

Comment: I'v edited the script to follow as yours but the main error `TypeError: Cannot read property '$$phase' of null` still persist.

Comment: what version of angular you are using?

Comment: can you post your json structure?

Comment: Please see edited list.html.you can use `{{$index}}` to get index.you dont have to use `indexOf()`

Comment: I'm using AngularJS v1.6.0-rc.2. I've added my data.json structure. Really appreciates your time. Thanks nikky.

Comment: I've modified list.html to use `{{$index}}` but it actually messed up the details page if I sorts the list. It will returns details of different hero instead.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention it earlier, the main error still persist even if I use `{{$index}}`

Comment: just use some stable version of angular js .latest is 1.5.9. it will solve that issue.And to get correct indexed item in detail page. you can use `<a href="#/details/{{hero.indexOf(item)}}">`

Comment: Hey nikky, thank you so much for pointing that out. I've changed it to AngularJS v1.5.9 and the error disappear. The fragment identifier also now use # instead of #! which actually bothers me too earlier.